# Extract JSON response status code from Sampler Result by using JSON extractor

Tags: jmeter

I'm writing a script in Beanshell and validating it by checking first the response status that JSON response has sent i.e "200" but unable to find out the way to extract it.

[image]

Comment: got it by using ResponseCode readonly variable. No need to use any extractor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as [Groovy performance is much better than other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so consider migrating to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) on next available opportunity.
2. You won't be able to use JSON Extractor there as this [`200` status code is related to HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200). Normally JMeter automatically considers HTTP status codes below 400 as successful, however if you need to perform an explicit check I would recommend going for [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion). The relevant configuration would be

   [image]
3. If you still want to continue with checking response status code via scripting you can do it using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and the following code:

   ```
   if (!SampleResult.getResponseCode().equals("200")) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Response code was not 200, received: " + SampleResult.getResponseCode())
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) for checking HTTP status

[image]

> Field to Test Instructs JMeter which field of the Request or Response to test.
>
> Response Code - e.g. 200

Comment: Thanks for your response! I really appreciate it.

Comment: How do we then store the result (response code) in a variable?